# Entity Framework with two separate DBContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4, and I am getting this error:

> A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary
>   key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   FK_Table1_Table2_ColumnId ]

Where `Table1` is in one `DBContext`:

```
public class Database1DB : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Table1> TableOne { get; set; }
}
```

and `Table 2` is in another `DBContext`:

```
public class Database2DB : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Table2> TabeTwo {get;set;}
}
```

`Table 1` has a foreign key reference to `Table2`'s column like this:

```
public class Table1
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("Table2")
   public int ColumnId {get;set;}

   public virtual Table2 Table2 {get;set;}
}

public class Table2
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot model relations between entities defined in different contexts. Related entities must be in the same context to make it work. In your case you can simply use:

```
public class Table1
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int ColumnId {get;set;}
}

public class Table2
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

And you will have to handle relation manually.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me before, I was just hoping there would be a way to  link them.